# Is List Joined Teams API Working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Working with Teams preview API and attempting to get all of the Teams of which the current person is a member.  I don't get any authorization errors, but instead get a 400 - Bad Request as a response.  Bad Request is a REALLY strange error for a GET request with no parameters, i.e. we're just asking for https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams using the access token we just got from Azure AD.

Is this just not working right now?  Or is there something maybe missing from the documentation?  Or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Without seeing the token, some code,  and/or HTTP traces of the traffic, the community could merely be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2/27/18: this has been fixed.

It's an active bug we are tracking.

Comment: Perfect - that's what I was hoping.  Thanks Bill.